# Bash not evaluating variable when redirecting command output

Tags: bash

I want a shell script to process many input files.  I am using variables for input names and renaming intermediate files.  I am unable to redirect output to a filename.

The shell script is run like this:

```
./trim_pair_align_ab1.sh 116102 128861
```

The script can echo the variables correctly (lines 15 and 16) and they match expectation.

```
./temp/45739_1_PET22-001_116102_00_trim.fastq
./temp/45739_1_PET22-001_116102_00_trim.fasta
```

It can't evaluate the filename when the command redirects output

```
line 17: temp/$(echo $f|sed 's/_trim.fastq/_trim.fasta/'): No such file or directory
```

```
8 for f in *.fastq
9 do
10 seqtk trimfq -q 0.05 $f > ./temp/$(echo $f|sed 's/.fastq/_trim.fastq/')
11 done
12 
13 for f in `eval ls ./temp/*$1*_trim.fastq`;
14 do
15 echo $f
16 echo $(echo $f|sed 's/_trim.fastq/_trim.fasta/')
17 seqtk seq -A $f > ./temp/$(echo $f|sed 's/_trim.fastq/_trim.fasta/')
18 done
```

Why does the output redirect work on line 10 but not on line 17?
What is making line 17 literal rather than evaluated?

Comment: You need to split lines of code so you can see what is happening.  Do something like `filename=./temp/$(echo $f|sed 's/_trim.fastq/_trim.fasta/')` then `echo "$filename"`.  This`for f in eval ls ./temp/*$1*_trim.fastq;` is a strange way of doing things, why do you need `ls`?  Why not just `for f in  ./temp/*"$1"*_trim.fastq`?

Comment: All the unquoted values (`echo $f` instead of `echo "$f"`) are also sources of additional hard-to-predict behavior. See [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).

Comment: ...for line 17, it should be `seqtk seq -A "$f" >"./temp/$(sed 's/_trim.fastq/_trim.fasta/' <<<"$f")"`

Comment: ...*if* you were still going to use `sed` at all, instead of going the much more efficient route and using a [parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) instead.

Comment: ...a PE version would be more like `seqtk seq -A "$f" >"./temp/${f%.fastq}.fasta"`

Comment: @JoeT, ...anyhow, if you want complete, firm, tested answer, you need to give us code we can copy-and-paste to see the exact same problem, without needing to do any setup ourselves beforehand. If that means your code needs to have a file named `foo_trim.fastq` created, f/e, then you should actually *create* that file as part of the [mcve]. Similarly, if your code needs a `$1`, use `set -- foo` to set it, or just modify it so it hardcodes a reasonable value. See also "Tricks for Trimming" at http://sscce.org/

Comment: ...also, note that your code is going to be looking for `./temp/temp/`, which presumably doesn't exist, and is thus presumably the cause of your "no such file or directory" (because there's already a `./temp` in `f`'s contents, but you're adding a second one in the redirection).

Comment: Line 13: _Don't do that_. Use `for f in ./temp/*$1*_trim.fastq` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command substitution *is* being expanded; the shell is simply printing the code you gave it, not the result of that expansion. For the real issue, you'll want to look further.

---

Take a close look at your `echo` showing the result of your command substitution:

```
./temp/45739_1_PET22-001_116102_00_trim.fasta
```

It **already has** a `./temp` prefix.

When you add a second such prefix in your redirection (`>./temp/$(...)`), you're making your code try to create a file in `./temp/temp/`. This directory doesn't exist, so you get an error.

---

That said, a better implementation would look like:

```
for f in ./temp/*"$1"*_trim.fastq; do
  seqtk seq -A "$f" >"${f%.fastq}.fasta"
done
```

Comment: upvoted;  @JoeT : to expand on this answer a bit, the original line 13 runs `ls` on each of a long list of individual files; you might have been expecting what happens when `ls` operates on a single directory, the result of which is a long list of files;  these two things are similar, but different; notably, in the latter case, the directory name itself is *not* part of the output